# Smooth Scroll Javascript fails on one Mac (Chrome) but works on another Mac (Chrome)

Tags: javascript

We have a smooth scroll script that fails on some Mac machine (latest chrome).

We tweaked the script a little bit and it appears to be working on all Macs now.

But we have no idea why.

Can someone help?

Before (That fails to smooth scroll correctly for some Mac/Chrome test machine):

```
var topID = (ua("safari")) ? "body" : "html";

$(".SmoothScroll").unbind().click(function(){
    var link = $(this).attr("href");
    if(link.charAt(0)=="#" && link.charAt(1)!="") {
        var offset = $(link).offset();
        var tid = setTimeout(function() {
            $(topID).stop().animate({scrollTop: offset.top}, 800, "easeInOutCubic", function() {
                location.href = link;
            });
        }, 10);
        return false;
    }
});
```

After fix (works on all machine)

```
//var topID = (ua("safari")) ? "body" : "html";
var $root = $('html, body');

$(".SmoothScroll").unbind().click(function(){
    var link = $(this).attr("href");
    if(link.charAt(0)=="#" && link.charAt(1)!="") {
        var offset = $(link).offset();
        var tid = setTimeout(function() {
            $root.stop().animate({scrollTop: offset.top}, 800, "easeInOutCubic", function() {
                location.href = link;
            });
        }, 10);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Basically changing $(topID) to $('html, body') appears to working. But why? What is happening and what could be the reason that the previous script fails on some Mac+Chrome?

Comment: Never do smooth scroll on a website, there are users who are unable to stand watching to smooth scrolling (like me), they get headaches when they watch it

Answer (score 0):

You probably do not have the same version of safari on both macs